# How to convert Text into upper case in textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have created a text box which can accept only one character. When the user types anything into the box, I want it converted into upper case.

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? WPF?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please in the future include what you have tried and the problem you are having with it.

Answer (score 6):

Set [TextBox.CharacterCasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.charactercasing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `CharacterCasing.Upper`.

```
textBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

Answer (score 2):

Right-click your textbox, and then click Properties.
In the Properties window, locate the CharacterCasing property, and then click to select Upper from the list.

(Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818363)

Comment: There is no option like CharacterCasing present in property section of visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Use `KeyDown` event and check the input key. Then use `String.ToUpper()`. For example:

```
private void YourTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    YourTextBox.Text = YourTextBox.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string lower = "converted from lowercase";
Console.WriteLine(lower.ToUpper());
```

Take a look at this: [How to convert strings to lower, upper, or title (proper) case by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312890)

Answer (score -1):

You could either change the textbox's casing to upper case like this:

```
TextBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

Or you could create an event which is executed when the textbox's text has changed.

```
TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text.ToString().ToUpper();
```

And so whenever someone types something inside of the textbox it will be changed to upper case, but I do not think that this is a good idea. I recommend using my first advice.

Comment: This is compile-time error :)

Comment: @Lynx tip: change it to: `TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text.ToString().ToUpper();`

Comment: `Text` is already string. No need to call `ToString()` on it.

Comment: Yeah, there has been long time since i have been last using winforms.